# Inheritance.JOINED, insert cause unnecessary update

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have two entities with inheritance relation between them, Content and Image. The inheritance strategy is JOINED. When I insert an Image, it does 3 queries : insert in Content table, insert in Image table and then update the content table. All the updated values are equal to the inserted ones (no real modification done)

Any clue why?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "content_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 255) 
public class Content {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "content_id_sequence_generator", sequenceName = "content_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "content_id_sequence_generator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "locale")
    private String locale;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image extends Content {

    @Column(name = "credit")
    private String credit;
}
```

When I do a CRUDRepository.save(image) :

```
insert 
into
    pfu.content(locale, id) values('en', 1000)
insert 
into
    pfu.image(credit, id) values('author', 1000)
update
    pfu.content 
set locale='en' where id=1000
```

Everything is done in one transaction and I do not modify anything in the saved object. Note that I guess it has a link with the inheritance but that is just a guess

Comment: You should ask any of the Hibernate commiters. For example https://vladmihalcea.com/

Comment: Can you add more precisely all the queries, please? By the way, as it's a joined inheritance the annotation `DiscriminatorColumn` is not needed. You may want to specify the identifier column on the child entity by using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.

Comment: @victorgallet not much to add in the queries. I'll do some modification. Thanks for the advice, I will definitely fix these annotations.